# htaccess - rewrite rule while keeping end of query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve a rewrite rule that contains part of a query string

I would like the following url:

```
/cart.php?a=add&pid=1     // with "1" being a dynamic integer
```

to be:

```
/checkout?pid=1    // with "1" being the dynamic corresponding integer
```

I tried the following but it's not working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^pid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^checkout$ ./cart.php?a=add&pid=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the QSA (Query String Append) flag, to preserve the original string eg.

```
 RewriteRule ^checkout$ ./cart.php?a=add [QSA,L]
```